# How to enter text at the beginning of JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Is there a way to add functionality that would enable a user to type into a JTextField but the cursor stays at the beginning of the input, thus making the text backward?

Example:

User types '5'

5 is displayed

User types '9'

95 is displayed

Comment: You could read the latest character the user types, then print the String with the character at the start into the JTextField

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to happen only with numbers, I suggest you to use a `JSpinner` component instead of a `JTextField`. But with textField you can achieve it like this:

```
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    AbstractDocument document = (AbstractDocument) field.getDocument();
    document.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            offset = 0;//Insert string at offset 0
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }
        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
                throws BadLocationException {
            offset = 0; //Insert string at offset 0
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        }
    });
```